# Working with more than one datetime format in python

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

Below is the sample data

```
Datetime

11/19/2020 9:48:50 AM
12/17/2020 2:41:02 PM
2020-02-11 14:44:58
2020-28-12 10:41:02
2020-05-12 06:31:39
```

11/19/2020 is in mm/dd/yyyy whereas 2020-28-12 is yyyy-dd-mm.

After applying pd.to_datetime below is the output that I am getting.

```
Date
2020-11-19 09:48:50
2020-12-17 22:41:02
2020-02-11 14:44:58
2020-28-12 10:41:02
2020-05-12 06:31:39
```

If the input data is coming with slash (/) i.e 11/19/2020 then format is mm/dd/yyyy in input itself and when data is coming with dash (-) i.e 2020-02-11 then the format is yyyy-dd-mm. But after applying pd.to_datetime datetime is getting interchanged.

The first two output is correct. The bottom three needs to be corrected as

```
2020-11-02 14:44:58
2020-12-28 10:41:02
2020-12-05 06:31:39
```

Please suggest to have common format i.e yyyy-mm-dd format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with specify both formats and `errors='coerce'` for missing values if no match and then replace them by another `Series` in [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', errors='coerce')

df['datetime'] = d1.fillna(d2)
print (df)
             datetime
0 2020-11-19 09:48:50
1 2020-12-17 14:41:02
2 2020-11-02 14:44:58
3 2020-12-28 10:41:02
4 2020-12-05 06:31:39
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Actually I need hours and minutes as well . So without removing time could you suggest the alternative ?

Comment: @AB14 - How working only `pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])` ?

Comment: using pd.to_datetime I am getting hours and minutes but also mixed datetime  i.e yyyy/ dd/mm and yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: @AB14 - How is possible distinguish between `yyyy/ dd/mm` and `yyyy/mm/dd` e.g. if `12/10/2020 2:41:02 PM` ? It is `yyyy/ dd/mm` or `yyyy/mm/dd` ?

Comment: The sample data is for November and December months

Comment: @AB14 - Hmm, so how is parsed `11/12/2020 9:48:50 AM` ? it is Nov or Dec?

Comment: @ jezreal. Rightly pointed out. It can be distinguished from input data itself. If the input data is coming with slash (/) i.e 11/19/2020 then format is mm/dd/yyyy in input itself and when data is coming with dash (-) i.e 2020-02-11 then the format is yyyy-dd-mm. But after applying pd.to_datetime datetime is getting interchanged. I hope I able to clear the doubt this time. Appreciate your opinion.

Comment: @AB14 - So it means `df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])` working well? If not, can you edit question with problematic data?

Comment: @ jezreal No its not working fine ! I am getting mixed kind of datetime. I have edited the question now.

Comment: @AB14 - OK, please add problematic datetimes, because now datetiems in question working well.

Comment: @ jezreal. Please have a look at revised problem statement.